# insert value into dropdownlist telerik by jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, telerik

I have a view

```
@(Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("InstrumentType").BindTo(Model.MITypesList).Enable(!Model.IsReadOnlyOtherProperties).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "instrument-type" }))
```

how can I insert value to input field?

all of this don't work

```
$(".instrument-type input").val('bla-bla');
$("#InstrumentType input").val('bla-bla');
$("#InstrumentType").val('bla-bla');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-combobox-client-api-and-events.html#select

```
var dropDown =  $("#InstrumentType").data("tDropDownList");
dropDown.select(arrayList.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the class of the input is `instrument-type`, you will want to use

```
$('.instrument-type').val('something');
```

You could even do `$('input.instrument-type').val('something');`

Comment: I need to insert in class="t-input"